# E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Hello I'm new to the angular and Protractor I am Getting " E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199" this error on my Code

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js'],
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',

},
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
framework: 'jasmine',
}
```

but when I tried to run protrator by the following command "protrator "filepath\conf.js", Getting "E-launcher process exited with error code 199" error. Can anyone please let me know, where I'm doing mistake? 
I am using chrome 54 and Protractor Version 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try use chromedriver 2.27, then chromedriver 2.34 if 2.27 not fix your issue.
Which chromedriver you used?